# How to create a dynamic sliding screens in Android and show given below layout

Tags: android

I have a layout which has a dynamically generated radiobuttons and a submit button which gets the value of selected radiobuttons on SUBMIT button. Now I want to create a dynamically generated sliding view for (n) pages where i can show same layout for different pages. Below is my approach and a working code. Thanks in advance

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] application = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ" };                     
    private String[] device = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ" }; 
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    private RadioButton btn;
    private RadioButton btn2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    RadioButton button1;
    RadioButton button2;
    Button selectall;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkButtonClick();
        drawRadiobuttons();

    }

    private void checkButtonClick() {

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("");

                // Get selected radiobuttons
                if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 1 : " + text1);
                }

                if (radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 2 : " + text2);
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Data Posting : APPLICATION : "
                                + text1 + " \nDEVICE : " + text2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

    }

    private void drawRadiobuttons(){

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        for (int i = 0; i < application.length; i++) {
            button1 = new RadioButton(this);
            button1.setId(i);
            button1.setText(application[i]);
            hourButtonLayout.addView(button1);

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup2,
                                int checkedId2) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup2.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup2.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn.getId() == checkedId2) {
                                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "You selected : " + text1,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio2); 
        for (int i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
            button2 = new RadioButton(this);
            button2.setId(i);
            button2.setText(device[i]);
            hourButtonLayout2.addView(button2);

            radioGroup2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup,
                                int checkedId) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn2 = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn2.getId() == checkedId) {
                                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "You selected : " + text2,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Select Question1"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:checkedButton="@+id/sound" >
                </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:text="Select Question2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="560dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:checkedButton="@+id/sound">
                </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting you right, by `sliding views` you mean `ViewPager`.
You can parametrize `ViewPager`'s adapter, i.e. pass the number of pages to your `Adapter`'s constructor.
Have a look at `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

1. In your button click listener calculate your number of pages needed (n).
2. Pass it in `Intent` to new `Activity`.
3. Implement your own `FragmentViewPager` and pass your `n` value to its constructor.
4. ...
5. PROFIT!

Sample  [here.](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: Thanks @agamov - Do you think ViewPager will fulfill my need? Can you show me an example with my above code?

Comment: Thanks @agamov, but i wish i had a sample code as i am not sure how will i get the values of selectedradiobutton for each views as i am going to iterate same layouts in all fragments